# X.509 Certificates for XML Signature and TLS

Tags: x509certificate, tls1.2, pki, xml-signature

What is the difference between an X.509 PKI certificate used for TLS and one used for XML Signatures?  My assumption is that they are the same.  However, the certificate used for TLS is invoked at the Transport Layer, and the certificate used for XML Signatures is invoked at the application layer.

Answer (score 2):

He he, You basically answered it in the question itself, there is no difference .   X.509 is a stadrdardized format/data-structure to represent the contents of a digital certificate . An X.509 formatted PKI certificate used for TLS and one used for XML Signatures are no different. These are just 2 separate usecases.  An X.509 certificate can be used in XML signatures, encrypting mail, signing pdf, can be used in TLS for https and in a volley of other use cases as well. [enter link description here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280)

For more details of the x509 standard u can go through the following RFC :